# How to scarpe images inside the GALLERY of a Kickstarter project NOT the main body of the project?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the URLs of images that are in the gallery of this [Kickstarter project.](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/657779427/pkfs-the-best-firestarter?ref=category#) I ran the following code but only got the first image in the galley. How can I get the other two as well?

```
url = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/657779427/pkfs-the-best-firestarter?ref=category#'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
x = soup.select('img[src^="https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/"]')

img_links = []
for img in x:
    img_links.append(img['src'])
    
for l in img_links:
    print(l)
```

I do not want the first and second URLs that this code outputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scrape all the image urls from a Kickstarter webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63974962/how-to-scrape-all-the-image-urls-from-a-kickstarter-webpage)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, No the page you referred me to only scrape the URLs of images within the body of the projects. Some projects have a gallery (the URL in my question). I want the URLS of images in the gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print all images from gallery, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/657779427/pkfs-the-best-firestarter?ref=category#'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
gallery_url = url.split('?')[0] + '/showcase.js'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(gallery_url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.select('.prototype-gallery__slide-media img'):
    print(img['src'])
```

Prints:

```
https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/014/851/422/7313aae8ee7ef1995effda55e4f78e79_original.jpg?ixlib=rb-2.1.0&w=700&fit=max&v=1481510259&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=25909e926203b8b6f46b44ac609b1013
https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/014/851/425/2a9cbad82f065900950410bb189f3e2e_original.jpg?ixlib=rb-2.1.0&w=700&fit=max&v=1481510280&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=1cb81e0218c480904db1e1d84c80fe6f
https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/assets/014/851/429/62577b8e7b25c0e4323cbb45835703e1_original.jpg?ixlib=rb-2.1.0&w=700&fit=max&v=1481510329&auto=format&frame=1&q=92&s=a3f14b32e9f87499b27855dd66047cb3
```